# How to submit an OSX app with a COMMAND LINE helper in its bundle

Tags: xcode, macos, sandbox, code-signing

So, I'm basically in the same situation [**that was discussed here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230168/submit-an-osx-app-with-helper-app-in-its-bundle) **BUT** I can't apply the proposed solution because the helper app I'm building to add to my main app bundle it's a command line executable and its own XCode project doesn't have a bundle name, embedded.provisionfile nor entitlements.

My app has been rejected two times by "not having that executable sandboxed". Well, the main app is sandboxed and the command line executable appears to be codesigned.

If I run:

`$ codesign --display --verbose=4 ./myFile`

I get:

```
Executable=/path/to/my/executable/myFile
Identifier=myFile
Format=Mach-O thin (i386)
CodeDirectory v=20100 size=43918 flags=0x0(none) hashes=2188+5 location=embedded
Hash type=sha1 size=20
CDHash=f28731c0d2482e0b0252efe0f1d33525a292f7c0
Signature size=4358
Authority=3rd Party Mac Developer Application: My name
Authority=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Signed Time=08/02/2013 03:15:58
Info.plist=not bound
Sealed Resources=none
Internal requirements count=1 size=188
```

So I think the command is already signed. What's the proper method to sandbox and codesign this kind of file?.

Comment: I have the same problem, was this problem ever resolved?

Comment: No. I ended up replacing the command file by another which had the source code available.