# How to codesign an Command line tool application which is included inside another mac osx application

Tags: xcode, macos, code-signing, command-line-tool

Hello I tried to Use macosvpn script inside my project I am not able to validate the application to submit to app store,

I tried following links

[How to submit an OSX app with a COMMAND LINE helper in its bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765124/how-to-submit-an-osx-app-with-a-command-line-helper-in-its-bundle)

[Mac OS app, sandbox with command line tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821632/mac-os-app-sandbox-with-command-line-tool)

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/codesign.1.html

using command codesign --entitlements ./entitlements.plist -s "copy & paste your certificate from keychain" ./commandlinetool

I can code sign but the application wont run after signing, because I guess I am using wrong certificate to sign applicaiton.

Comment: There's a couple things that could be going wrong, in addition to issues with codesigning.  How are you trying to run your command line tool from your app? Are you trying to run that command line tool as "root" or "admin"?  Are there any errors that are being displayed in your Xcode console or in the Console.app?

Comment: I am running  it as STPrivilegedTask, Also It is working fine and does not display any error but when validating the application it shows 0 Entitlements inside the [link](http://postimg.org/image/4ewe5880b/)  Error without entitlements shown here [link](http://postimg.org/image/5dcr7ilcb/)  and when I add entitlements in the Command line tool like [link](http://postimg.org/image/tidgp85mz/) and then add entitlements in the build settings in command line tool like [link](http://postimg.org/image/yv2b3ctjf/) The Validation does not show any error, But the command line tools script does not work.

Comment: When I add entitlments like [link](http://postimg.org/image/yv2b3ctjf/) then the script runs and ask for admin credentials and when I remove entitlements It shows error   "Sorry, without superuser privileges I won't be able to add any VPN interfaces."                        : ` if (SCPreferencesLock(prefs, TRUE)) {
        DDLogDebug(@"Gained superhuman rights.");
    } else {
        DDLogError(@"Sorry, without superuser privileges I won't be able to add any VPN interfaces.");
        return 31;
    }`